# Fetching translations based on language header with axios isn't working

Tags: javascript, axios, next.js

I'm trying to build website consist of one page containing many components.
I want to fetch data for each component
so I try use `Promise.all()` in index page
but the problem is that translations from API don't appear only one language appears.
I used Next.js Internationalized Routing,
but when I only make `axios.get()` for one component it works.
What is the problem & how can I solve that?

`header.js`

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import en from './locales/en';
import ar from './locales/ar';
import Axios from 'axios';
import Cookie from 'js-cookie';
import {useState } from 'react';
const Header = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const [langCode, setLangCode] = useState('en');    
    Axios.defaults.headers.common['Language'] = langCode;

    const { locale } = router;
    const t = locale === 'en' ? en : ar;
    const changeLanguage = (locale) => {
        Cookie.set('lang', locale);
        router.push(router.pathname, router.asPath, { locale });
        setLangCode(locale);

    };
const lang = Cookie.get('lang')
    return (
        <header>
            <button onClick={() => changeLanguage(lang == 'en' ? 'ar' : 'en')}>
                change lang
            </button>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <Link href="/">
                        <a>{t.home}</a>
                    </Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </header>
    );
};
export default Header;
```

index.js

```
import Axios from "axios";
import Header from "../components/Header";
const index = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html:  data.details}}/>
    </div>
  );
};
index.getInitialProps = async () => {
  const res = await Axios.get(`https://api.trueapps.co/api/who-we-are`);
  const data = await res.data.data;
  return { data };
};
export default index;
```

AND this is the code in `index.js` when I use `Promise.all()`.

`index.js`

```
import Axios from "axios";
import Header from "../components/Header";
const index = (data) => {
    console.log(data.about);
    console.log(data.services);
    console.log(data.team);
      return (
        <div>
          <Header />
        </div>
      );
    };
index.getInitialProps = async () => {

    const [about, team, services] = await Promise.all([
        fetch(`https://api.trueapps.co/api/who-we-are`).then((r) => r.json()),
        fetch(`https://api.trueapps.co/api/team`).then((r) => r.json()),
        fetch(`https://api.trueapps.co/api/services`).then((r) => r.json()),
    ]);
        return { about, team, services};

};
export default index;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're setting the default `Language` header in `axios` (`Axios.defaults.headers.common['Language'] = langCode;`) but then making the requests using `fetch`.

Using `axios` to make the requests in `index.getInitialProps` should do the trick.

```
index.getInitialProps = async () => {
    const [aboutRes, teamRes, servicesRes] = await Promise.all([
        Axios.get(`https://api.trueapps.co/api/who-we-are`),
        Axios.get(`https://api.trueapps.co/api/team`),
        Axios.get(`https://api.trueapps.co/api/services`)
    ]);
    return {
        about: aboutRes.data,
        team: teamRes.data,
        services: servicesRes.data
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are mixing Axios and fetch API together. Maybe you need to change to Axios's get instead of fetch API from the below code.

```
    index.getInitialProps = async () => {

    const [about, team, services] = await Axios.all([
        await fetch(`https://api.trueapps.co/api/who-we-are`).then((r) => r.json()),
        fetch(`https://api.trueapps.co/api/team`).then((r) => r.json()),
        fetch(`https://api.trueapps.co/api/services`).then((r) => r.json()),
    ]);
        return { about, team, services};

};
```

Comment: using axios.get() throw this error => Circular structure in "getInitialProps"        , so I replaces axios.all() with Promise.all() but the problem of language still there

Comment: Can you please send the sample code or create a code sandbox, where I can see the real issue.